# Get all files from azure blob container using rest API, I am already tried this code but i am facing 403 error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I already get containers using RestAPI
Get all files from the blob storage container  using RestAPI.

I already use this API.

```
   private const string ListofFilesURL = "https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list&maxresults=10";
```

My Code is below,

```
 public async void ListofFilessinBlob(string containername)
     {

            string Requesturl = string.Format(ListofFilesURL, storageAccount, containername);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Requesturl);
            string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader2("GET", now, request, storageAccount, storageKey, containername));
            // var response =  request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
            await request.GetResponseAsync();
            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                resp.StatusCode.ToString();
                WebHeaderCollection header = resp.Headers;

                var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
                using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
                {
                    string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }

        }
```

My Authorization header method is below,

private string AuthorizationHeader2(string method, string now, HttpWebRequest request, string storageAccount, string storageKey, string containerName)
    {

```
    string headerResource = $"x-ms-date:{now}\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11";
    string canonicalizedResource = $"/{storageAccount}/{containerName}\ncomp:list\nmaxresults:10";
    var contentEncoding = "";
    var contentLanguage = "";
    var contentLength = "";
    var contentMd5 = "";
    var contentType = "";
    var date = "";
    var ifModifiedSince = "";
    var ifMatch = "";
    var ifNoneMatch = "";
    var ifUnmodifiedSince = "";
    var range = "";
    var stringToSign = $"{method}\n{contentEncoding}\n{contentLanguage}\n{contentLength}\n{contentMd5}\n{contentType}\n{date}\n{ifModifiedSince}\n{ifMatch}\n{ifNoneMatch}\n{ifUnmodifiedSince}\n{range}\n{headerResource}\n{canonicalizedResource}";
    var signature = "";
    using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageKey)))
    {
        var dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
    }
    String AuthorizationHeader = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", storageAccount, signature);
    return AuthorizationHeader;
}
```

[image]

You can see this error. I already tried this code.

Comment: Please read the section titled `Constructing the Canonicalized Resource String` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services.

Comment: @GauravMantri . thanks for reply. I already added authorization header . But in get response i am facing exception(403). Can you please check my code :)

Comment: Shouldn't you just use a Shared Access Signature instead of going to all that bother to hash a key? Then you could test it easily in postman too.

Comment: @MikeWise Or use .Net SDK. I really don't understand why would one want to go through the hassle of implementing REST API when you have an excellent and well maintained SDK available.

Comment: I went to REST recently for a unity app. While there is something Azure SDK like for Mono, it is apparently not that good, and I didn't want to add all that code just to save a simple blob - the REST call was like 10 lines of code and needed no new libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `canonicalizedResource` string does not include all the querystring parameters. It should be:

```
string canonicalizedResource = $"/{storageAccount}/{containerName}\ncomp:list\nmaxresults:10\nrestype:container";
```

From the documentation link:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @GauravMantri . It is works. you r right i missed that one.